# midline and amplitude of the curve $y = 3\csc (\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3})+2$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Can anyone please tell me what is midline and amplitude of the curve $y = 3\csc \left(\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3}\right)+2.$

**My Attempt:**  As maximum and minimum of $y = 3\csc (\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3})+2$ do not exist. The amplitude of it will also not exist. $3\csc (\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3})$ does not exist when $(\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3}) = 0$. Then how we will find the midline ?

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by mid line ? Is it symmetric axis ? Graph will be same as cosec X just will shift on +x-axis   by π/3 and by 2 on y axis . So new axis which was before at ${\pi \over 2}$ will be at ${\pi \over 2}+{\pi \over 3}$.

Comment: The symmetric axis can be obtained by averaging the y-values of the relative minima and maxima to obtain $y=2$.

Comment: What will be the amplitude ?@dodoturkoz

Comment: As far as I know, the amplitudes for curves such as secant and cosecant are not considered for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the cosecant function, you notice that it consists of repeating intervals of length $\pi$, alternating one above $y=1$, the next below $y=-1$. scaling and shifting $\theta$ will just scale/shift the intervals, but not the amplitude. When you multiply by $3$ you change the amplitude, and then you shift it up by $2$. So the midline will be $y=2$.
[image]

Comment: What will be the amplitude of the function ?@Andrei

Comment: @sani If you define the amplitude as the maximum distance from the midline, then the answer is $\infty$